# polynomial norm and Banach spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the linear space of polynomials on [$a$, $b$] normed by $\rVert$$\centerdot$$\rVert$_max norm. Is this normed linear space a Banach space? My professor said it is not, but then could I use contradiction? Haven't been able to come up with a good Cauchy sequence argument, though. I would appreciate all the help I could get, thank you.

Comment: It might be easier to prove that the space isn't Banach by "counter-example" instead of contradiction. If you can come up with an explicit sequence of polynomials that doesn't converge to a polynomial under the max-norm, then you won't need to worry about generalities.

Comment: What is a good counterexample in this case?

Comment: see my answer for a counterexample.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Approximate the exponential function by its Taylor polynomials. You should also prove that the exponential function is *not* a polynomial, not even in an interval.

Comment: I am working on the same problem and was wondering about this. Does the argument work like this: The taylor series is convergent (in what space?) => the Taylor series is cauchy. Since it is made up of polynomials it is a cauchy sequence in P[a,b] but is not convergent => P[a,b] not complete. Does that look OK?

Answer (score 1):

I think I remember using Baire Category to do this.  Let $A_n$ be the space of polynomials of degree less than n and clearly the space of linear polynomials is a countable union of the $A_n$.  Then prove this is closed but does not contain an interval.  I think proving it is closed is the hard part.

Comment: Unfortunately, my class hasn't even reached Baire Category Theory yet.

Comment: Oh, okay.  Well, when you do get there, this is a good thing to try to work through (there is a fairly small set of problems that practice Baire Category and I think this is one of the easier ones I've seen)

Comment: not to threadjack, but can you share some of the other problems and/or a reference to find them?

Comment: @user1736: A nice problem is: if $f: (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous with the property that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(nx) = 0$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$ then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$. The analogous result doesn't hold for $f(n + x)$. You can find a number of such exercises in any book on functional analysis, mostly in connection with the fundamental theorems (uniform boundedness, open mapping, etc.) Another of my favourites: show that $[0,1]$ is not the union of a countably many non-empty, pairwise disjoint closed sets.